# Can someone explain what is active and debounce for?

Tags: lua, roblox

I dont know what is active and debounce for i mean what are they doing why they are there ? Can someone explain please ?
Ok so here is the code:

```
 
local debounce = false
local active = false
 
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input,isTyping)
    if isTyping then
        return
    elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        if debounce == false and active == false then
            debounce = true
 
            blabla:FireServer(active)
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: well that's some simple conditions and two boolean values. I don't know what there is not to understand. first they are both false, then if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and not isTyping debounce becomes true and that function is called with active as argument.. there is not more to explain. simple conditional statements and assignments.

Comment: more context is needed if you want a deeper understanding of the purpose of those values, we would need at least all the statements where their values are changed, as well as any functions they are used as parameters in (like the code for `blabla:FireServer(active)`)

Comment: I didnt wanted the entire codes explanition just wanted to know how can u use active and what is it for i mean cant we change its name like skrrrt or something we only need to name it active? (and sorry if i am so dumb cuz i just started to learn lua like 4 days ago.) also thanks.

Comment: you can name variable however you like. a good programmer will never name a variable skrrrt as good variable names tell something about their purpose.  like input.KeyCode, you instantly know that this is the keycode of the input.  but no one knows what blabla is...

Answer (score 1):

local debounce variable its an a bool value, that used(in that script) to mark is the server event is already fired/firing(you can see that by "if debounce == false" field), if player pressing E key the event fires and the debounce's value setting to false, so event won't be fired again by that script, until you/code set it to true.
By the way, you can view all information about roblox's lua type at roblox's web site, here you can find post about bool values & variables
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Boolean

And the active its value used for remote event that created by server(server gets active variable by remote event for on-server function)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i get it now.